# Jenkins copy changed files from Jenkins to Windows server

Tags: jenkins

New to jenkins and trying to move files from the jenkins server over to a remote server.  What the best way to do this?  Both servers are windows servers. And I only want to move files that have been added or updated.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with 'jenkins'? Did you [search before](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+server+file+synching)? [Synchronize Files Between Windows Servers](http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-synchronize-files-between-windows-servers/) is the first result I got here.

Comment: I did search before. And this was a question for using https://jenkins.io/ and not a windows service